# UI Path How to Change Default Activities Properties

Tags: properties, uipath

[image: UI path properties screenshot]

Is it actually possible to change the default property in any of the UI path activities?

I want to do this is because I want the **On Element Appear** activity to have the *RepeatForever* property by default set to false, as I often use this activity to be done only once per running.

Comment: Very interesting question, but currently not possible. What you could do I copying it. Or you create a template. But both not exactly what you are searching for I know.

Answer (score 0):

Some properties could be managed through Project Settings in Studio click on the [gear icon](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/configuring-activity-project-settings) in the project panel. You could set up defaults for both Debug and Production runs.
https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/configuring-activity-project-settings